# C++のラムダ関数がローカル変数をキャプチャするときに関数ポインタに変換できなくなるのはなぜ？

Tags: c++

以下のコードがコンパイルできないのは何故なんでしょうか？

```cpp
void f() {
    int x;
    +[x]{};
}
```

一見コンパイルできると思ったのですが、GCCでもClangでもMSVCでもコンパイルエラーでした。
なお以下はコンパイルできるようです。

```cpp
void f() {
    +[]{};
}
```

Comment: 何故とは書いて無いようですが、そういう物のようです。[関数ポインタへの変換](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp11/lambda_expressions.html#convert-to-function-pointers) `キャプチャを含まない(つまり状態を持たない)ラムダ式によって生成されたクロージャオブジェクトは、同じパラメータ型と戻り値型のシグニチャを持つ関数ポインタに変換できる。`, [ラムダ式をCの関数ポインタへ変換](https://qiita.com/YukiMiyatake/items/8d10bca26246f4f7a9c8#%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%83%80%E5%BC%8F%E3%82%92c%E3%81%AE%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%83%9D%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%81%B8%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B) `キャプチャ変数がない場合のみ、同じ引数と戻り値の関数ポインタと互換性がある`

Comment: 英語のこの記事が同様の話題でしょうか。[Passing capturing lambda as function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28746744/9014308) その回答のどれかにも書かれていて、目的とは違うかもですが、仕様の版数が上がると別の方法もありそうです。[templateを用いてラムダ式をメンバ変数に保持させるにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？](https://teratail.com/questions/55961), [C++11とラムダ式のあれこれ](https://developers.wonderpla.net/entry/2014/11/25/162954), [lambda expression を 関数ポインタ型へと変換する](https://osyo-manga.hatenadiary.org/entry/20121205/1354674180)

Comment: なるほど。様々な解決策理解しました。大変勉強になりました。記事の共有ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

キャプチャする`int x`変数はスコープを抜けた時点で消去されます。しかし、ラムダ関数は別のスコープを持っています。**キャプチャする**と表現しているように、別の領域にコピーしていますし、それを破棄する処理も必要になります。つまり、ラムダ関数は関数の実行とは別にキャプチャしたオブジェクトの管理も必要になってきます。そうなると関数ポインターでは表現できなくなります。

Comment: なるほど。確かにラムダ関数の呼び出しは実質的にはメンバ関数呼び出しなんで、関数ポインタだけではダメで、*thisも引数に渡さないと呼び出せないですね。言われてみれば当たり前という感じでした。ありがとうございます。

Comment: ということは、キャプチャ無しのラムダ関数は実質的にはstaticなメンバ関数ということになるわけなんですね。今までキャプチャありのラムダ関数もキャプチャ無しのラムダ関数もあんまり区別していませんでしたが、そういう違いがあったんですね。

Answer (score 2):

> C++のラムダ関数がローカル変数をキャプチャするときに関数ポインタに変換できなくなるのはなぜ？

短い答え：C++実行環境において合理的な実装が不可能なためです。

---

思考実験として下記の関数`g`を考えます。関数`g`は「実行時に値が確定するローカル変数`x`を(コピー)キャプチャした関数ポインタ」を返す必要があります。

```
auto g()
{
  int x;
  std::cin >> x;
  // ラムダ式から関数ポインタへの変換に単項+演算子を利用
  return +[x]{};
}
```

この関数ポインタがさす先の実行可能コード（≒機械語命令列）はコンパイル時には生成不可能であり、プログラム実行時に実行可能コードを動的生成しなければなりません。また関数`g`が何度も呼び出されるシナリオでは異なる`x`値に応じた実行可能コードが必要となりますが、C++言語はガベージコレクタをもたないため実行可能コード片（≒動的に生成される関数）を破棄する契機がなくメモリを圧迫し続けます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。おっしゃられた通りラムダ関数はそのオブジェクト自体の情報がなければを呼び出せませんね。納得しました。